# How do I get Libreoffice to start or open documents?

Tags: 18.04, xubuntu, libreoffice

I have tried all of the suggestions that I could find here and the LO website (`--fix-missing`, `--fix-broken`, delete `libreoffice` in `./config/`, install `ubuntu-desktop`, `purge`/ `reinstall`, `reinstall`, added the LO ppa, and re-added the official repositories).

There has never been a LO process in `taskmanager` (I open the manager then clicked on the launcher or a file and switch back to the manager and nothing ever appears that I can see, assuming it will be listed starting with "l"). And, there are no error messages when starting from the command line. The OS is fully upgraded.

Edit:
output of ls -l libreoffice:

```
ls: cannot access 'libreoffice': No such file or directory
```

[image: libreoffice is installed]

@ ajgringo619 edit

I purged LO and deleted ~/.config/libreoffice, removed the LO ppa, restarted, installed, and restarted.

```
/usr/bin/libreoffice
```

Produces no information just a new prompt.

@ Bruni edit

```
ps -A | grep soffice
```

Produces no information just a new prompt.

However, this time I did see libreoffice 'self kill' in the taskmanager.

@ vanadium edit

Output of which libreoffice:

```
/usr/bin/libreoffice
```

Comment: Can you try it again, this time without the PPA? What happens when you run `/usr/bin/libreoffice` from the terminal? You said no error messages - but you get nothing?

Comment: please provide result of `ls -l libreoffice`

Comment: The process is called `soffice.bin`, so run `ps -A | grep soffice` .

Comment: Please restructure the question. First ask the question, then elaborate on what you eventually tried. It is difficult now to decipher what you really want to know.

Comment: After re-reading three times, I guess I understand you do not succeed in starting libreoffice at all, even though it is installed? `which libreoffice` will tell you at least whether the executable is there. Then execute it from the terminal as ajgingo619 already suggested. This may reveal error messages in the terminal that can point to the problem.

Comment: @DMon what is your Ubuntu version? Also please add output of `which libreoffice` and `apt-cache policy $(dpkg -S $(which libreoffice))` to the question.

Comment: Thanks N0rbert. However, I've become used to submitting tumbleweed questions and so I installed ApacheOffice. I'll be deleting this post.

Comment: I tried to edit my comment but wasn't allowed. This is not my first account. I get disappointed and stay away for so long that I forget my login information. I've been around for a long time.